# Trailing Slash Not Being Added to My .htaccess Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

The rules below are accomplishing what I want, i.e., www to non-www and http to https, however, I have two remaining issues:

Trailing slash should be added to all pages (**except pages that end with any type of modifier, e.g., /page#foo, page/foo.jpg, etc.**

Here are the current rules in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: See this https://helponnet.com/2021/05/07/add-traling-slash-to-urls-using-rewriterule/

Comment: _"should be added to all pages"_ - and what exactly is your definition of a "page"? (Not your _logical_ definition, I mean, but your _criteria_ that would allow to test for this within the .htaccess rewriting context.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The rules below are accomplishing what I want, i.e., www to non-www **and http to https**

The rule you posted does not specifically redirect HTTP to HTTPS, since it won't redirect `http://example.com/` (HTTP + non-www) requests. If you are seeing this redirect then *something else* is doing it.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

Incidentally, the first *condition* that checks that the `Host` header is not `localhost` is entirely superfluous since that must be true if the second *condition* is true. The two conditions are mutually inclusive.

> Trailing slash should be added to all pages (except pages that end with any type of modifier, e.g., `/page#foo`, `page/foo.jpg`, etc.)

It's impossible to detect *fragment identifiers* (aka *hash*) (ie. the `foo` in `/page#foo`) in `.htaccess` since this part of the URL (ie. `#foo`) is not sent to the server as part of the HTTP request. The `#foo` part of the URL is only used by client-side code/JavaScript. As far as the server is concerned, there is no difference between `/page#foo` and `/page`. If this is an issue for you then you can't force the trailing slash in `.htaccess`. However, the trailing slash would be added after `/page` not after `/page#foo` (if that is what you were thinking), ie. `/page#foo` would be redirected to `/page/#foo`, so this shouldn't be an issue.

You can add the following rule *before* your existing rule, just after the `RewriteEngine` directive:

```
# Append trailing slash to URL-path if omitted unless it looks like an actual file
RewriteCond $1 !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ https://%1/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^(.*[^/])$` matches any URL-path that does not already end with a slash. The URL-path is then captured in the `$1` backreference. The first *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) then checks that the URL-path does not end with what looks-like a file extension (ie. a dot followed by between 2 and 4 alphanumeric upper/lowercase characters). The second *condition* then just captures the domain name less any optional `www.` prefix, saving this in the `%1` backreference.

This also redirects to HTTPS and non-www domain name, so it avoids a potential second redirect by the rule that follows.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

If you are testing on localhost and localhost does not support HTTPS then modify the rule as follows in order to preserve HTTP on localhost only. For example:

```
RewriteCond $1 !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^()(localhost)$ [OR]
RewriteCond s%{HTTP_HOST} ^(s)(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ http%1://%2/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the trailing slash issue, but for some reason I'm seeing a bunch of /404.shtml/ in my organic traffic in the few hours since implementing. Weird, because I don't know what on this WP site would trigger this.

Comment: @Mattypants Change the _CondPattern_ in the first `RewriteCond` directive from `!\.\w{2,4}$` to `!\.\w{2,5}$` (ie. `4` to `5`). Although, as you say, you shouldn't be seeing requests to `/404.shtml` on a WP site in the first place - unless perhaps this is bot traffic that is requesting `/404.shtml` directly? (Or perhaps you have a front-end proxy that serves your static assets? But regardless, this would seem to be a 404?)

Comment: @Mattypants Note that if this is a WordPress site then these directives need to go near the top of the file, _before_ the WP code block, ie. _before_ the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.